# Accessing mapped objects in another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have mapped data from array object that is being fetched from an API at an interval of one second and rendered it to ListItem in React Native. As per the code below, how can i  get one of the mapped objects e.g
`{item.AskPrice}` and use it in another function that is outside the scope of the return statement to carry out other calculations

```js
function checkCondition(){
....
}

// Mapping of data

return(
    ...
    <View>
        {
            data.prices && data.prices.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <ListItem
                        key={index}
                        
                        bottomDivider>
                        <ListItem.Content>
                            <ListItem.Title>
                                {item.instrument}        
                                {item.AskPrice}        
                                {item.BidPrice}
                            </ListItem.Title>
                        </ListItem.Content>
                    </ListItem>
                )
            })
        }
    </View>
);
```

Comment: What do *other calculations* look like? Does it return jsx or are you doing some mathematical opeartion?

Comment: Is that a regular function or a custom hook? If it is a regular function, you can use it like `{mappedData(item.AskPrice)}` as you do in JS. If it is a custom hook you can't use it directly. We should know your intention here.

Comment: This is just a  part of the code.  I wanted to have a textinput where a user will input a price, for example: `1.14432`, then when this price is equal to the ` {item.AskPrice}`, an alert is triggered

Comment: Maybe {checkCondition(item.AskPrice) && item.AskPrice}, make sure checkCondition return true;

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments. If it's a regular function and not a hook then you can just call your function inside the `.map()` and do your calculations.

```
function useMappedData(price){
    // Do you calculation 
    // return result
}


return (
  <View>
    {data.prices && data.prices.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <ListItem key={index} bottomDivider>
            <ListItem.Content>
              <ListItem.Title>
                {item.instrument}
                {useMappedData(item.AskPrice)}
                {item.BidPrice}
              </ListItem.Title>
            </ListItem.Content>
          </ListItem>
        );
      })}
  </View>
);
```

Also if you have a unique id in your data object them you should use that in your `key={}` instead of the index of the map.

Comment: Unless `useMappedData` is a hook (as it sounds like from the name).

Comment: You're right. But I'm guessing that `useMappedData` will be used for a mathematical operation. He mentioned that he wants to pass `{item.AskPrice}` into it which I'm guessing is a number. The OP needs to clarify what he intends to do in the function.

Comment: My intention was to pass the textinput value, which is a number, as a parameter in the `useMappedData` function then compare  the value passed with the `{item.AskPrice}` to check if they are equal at an interval of one second

Comment: @user23424 ok that makes sense. I would guess that you're storing the textinput value into state? If so then you can directly access that input value in your `useMappedData` function or pass it alongside `item.AskPrice` when calling the function and make your alert when they are equal. Look into using a `useEffect()` hook for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I have tried passing the `item.AskPrice` but it throws an error `Property destructuring pattern expected`

Comment: @AKX. Its a name of the function. Let me change it to avoid confusion

Comment: @Tuaev the `{item.AskPrice}` as well as  `{item.BidPrice}` gets updated after every second. My goal was to have the same data to keep updating in the function such that when i console.log the `{item.AskPrice}` , it gets updated the same way as in the view. This will help in checking if the condition is fulfilled

Comment: You can do that by just returning the `price` from the function after you checked if it's equal to the input value. This way you have it in the function and the view.

Comment: @Tuaev  i have tried all of the above and none of them is working